# Tridion changes to do after I copy the CMS from production to test environment

Tags: content-delivery

I would like to copy all the content from production CMS to test/acceptance environment. 
Will do the complete database copy, not with content porter. 
I would like to know the Tridion changes to do in test environment after I am done with DB copy. For instance now I am analysing configuration components and publication properties where the changes are required. Please suggest me where else I have to do the changes in Tridion @ test environment.

Thank you.

Comment: I am doing complete 'functional' analysis, do not need to think about technical matters now.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the guidelines that I normally follow:

### Preparation

1. Back up the existing Tridion Content Manager (Tridion_cm), Broker and Session Preview databases in the Test environment
2. Back up the Tridion_cm database from the Production environment
3. Make a note of the SQL Server database names, the usernames and passwords for the existing Tridion CM, Broker(s) and Session Preview databases in Test.
4. Make a note of the Publication Target details in Test

### In the Test environment:

5. Restore the Tridion_cm database from Production (Step 1) over the existing Tridion_cm database.
6. Run a SQL command to update the system (MTS User) domain account that Tridion uses
7. Run a command to set all of the items within the Tridion_cm database as 'unpublished'
8. Reconfigure the restored Tridion_cm database to use the (SQL Server) username and password for Test (noted in Step 3)
9. Assuming that you are starting from fresh, and re-publishing all content...Delete the existing Broker and Session Preview databases
10. Create the new Broker and Session Preview databases using the SDL Tridion Database Powershell scripts. These new databases should have the same database names, usernames and passwords as before (noted in Step 3).
11. Set up the Publishing Targets again (noted in Step 4) and delete the old Production ones

### Testing

12. Test that the Content Management Explorer (CME) interface is working as expected, and that you can see Publications in the left hand panel of the Content Management Explorer.
13. Test that Publishing work as expected
14. Check all integrations and customisations (Custom Pages, Custom Storage Extensions, etc.)
15. Update any configuration needed on the web application (Publication Ids in config files, etc.)
16. Re-publish all pages and content and test the sites

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need the SQL scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen Tridion for a while, but from top of my head you will need to:

- Change MTSUser in the database, unless you are using directory user and it has enough rights
- Clean few tables in database, where machine names are stored, otherwise your event log will be full of "Unable to notify..." messages. Unfortunately I don't remember the table names
- Change your PublicationTargets to not accidentally publish something into wrong place

I'm pretty sure there's more

Comment: for my 'functional' analysis, your third point seems valid, thank you very much. I do not need to think about table names, the technical guy who actually do the copy will think about that.